# MSVC, x64, Is it possible to emit arbitrary bytes inside a function?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, x86-64, masm, inline-assembly

The MSVC x64 cl compiler, unfortunately, no longer support __asm instruction (inline assembler) inside the functions, and as a result of

```
__asm _emit <byte>
```

instruction also become unavailable, unlike gcc (which is support instruction like:

```
__asm __volatile__ (".byte " <byte> ";")
```

for any platform i386, x86-64 or even non-x86).

For me, it's a big obstacle for moving from MinGW to MSVC compiler.

I ask this question with the hope that probably anybody knows how to reserve or place some arbitrary sequence of bytes inside the machine-code of a function?

Comment: Is there a particular byte you are trying to emit? I'm curious if you are emitting data or instructions. If it is data, why do you have to emit them inside the function?

Comment: As far as I know, you simply can't.  GCC and clang typically optimize better, so if you're already using GNU C inline asm then why switch?  If it's to use AVX (because MinGW is probably still broken for stack-alignment on Windows), then use clang.

Comment: The alternative is to use the ICC (Intel) compiler which supports MSVC inline assembly in 64-bit code and also supports GCC style inline assembly.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Yes, it's particular bytes sets. If in short, it's related to my a build-in code protector from cracking. Unfortunately (as far I know) the Intel compiler is not free, and if we talk about my motivation (move from MinGW to MSVC), it's a google crashpad library, which I want to build in for improving application stability.
Unfortunately, on the Windows platform, it supports only form MSVC compiler.

Comment: I made some investigation and found that I can use intrinsic __nop() for "reserve" some bytes inside the function. But the problem is that I should create external tools for processing compiling binary and fill these values...